# Finding the closest integer value, rounded down, from a given array of integers

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out the best way to find the closest value, ROUNDED DOWN, in a List of integers using any n that is between two other numbers that are stored in a List. The all integers in this situation will ALWAYS be unsigned, in case that helps.

The assumptions are as follows:

- The List *always* starts at 0
- The List is *always* sorted ASC
- All integers in the List are unsigned (no need for `Math.Abs`)
- The number for comparison is always unsigned

For example:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 0, 2000, 4000, 8000, 8500, 9101, 10010 };
int myNumber = 9000;
int theAnswer; // should be 8500

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++) {
    if (i == numbers.Count - 1) {
      theAnswer = numbers[i];
      break;
    } else if (myNumber < numbers[i + 1]) {
      theAnswer = numbers[i];
      break;
    }
}
```

The previous code example works without any flaws.

Is there a <strike>better</strike> more succint way to do it?

Comment: This question is potentially more suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What you mean by better? Performance? Memory consumption? ... Anyway, try binary search.

Comment: If you are talking about a small list of numbers, then what you have here is fine and I would not spend any more time on it.  If you are talking about an arbitrarily large list of numbers, you may want to perform a more efficient search to find the 2 numbers myNumber is between.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan you are correct, "better" isn't the right word. I'll change it.

Comment: The succint way is `var theAnswer = numbers.Where(x >= myNumber).FirstOrDefault()` FirstOrDefault used in case when there is no number in list >= myNumber. If my assuu correct about `ROUNDED DOWN` the answer for your example is 9101.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [List<T>.BinarySearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/3f90y839.aspx) instead of enumerating elements of list in sequence.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 0, 2000, 4000, 8000, 8500, 9101, 10010 };
int myNumber = 9000;

int r=numbers.BinarySearch(myNumber);
int theAnswer=numbers[r>=0?r:~r-1];
```

Comment: Very nice use of information presented on MSDN! Thank you for forcing me to learn the bitwise compliment operator and for re-reading the [BinarySearch documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Filter list obtaining all values less than the `myNumber` and return last one:

```
theAnswer = numbers.Where(x => x <= myNumber ).Last();
```

Comment: `Last` would return an `int` and there is no `Select` method for `int`.

Comment: Also, I would not accept without proof that any Linq-based solution is better than the OP's solution, in terms of performance.

Comment: Why is this being down voted so much? This is exactly how I would do it. +1

Comment: @hatcyl Originally it was completely wrong, but a few edits improved it.

Comment: That's an O(n) solution, not better than the OP's solution.

Comment: @EricJ. The OP changed "better" to "succint", which this would definitely fit that.

Comment: "Better" is subjective. To me, better means easier to understand and more straight forward. Especially for a list of very few integers. Now, if he had a million ...

Comment: This is a good answer, but it requires Linq. I don't have a problem using Linq, but there might be a user who reads this at a different date who cannot use Linq. Upvoted regardless...not sure if I want to accept as the answer yet though. Thank you!!!!

Comment: What about "ROUNDED DOWN", how do you treat this term?

Answer (score 0):

A list can be indexed.

Start at the index in the middle of the list.  If you found the exact number, you are good.  If the number is less than the target number, search in the middle of the range from the start of the list to one less than the middle of the list.  If the number is greater than the target number, work with the opposite half of the list.  Continue this binary search until you find either an exact match, or the adjacent numbers that are smaller and larger than the target number.

Select the smaller of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 0, 2000, 4000, 8000, 8500, 9101, 10010 };
int myNumber = 9000;

int theAnswer = numbers[numbers.Count - 1];

if (theAnswer > myNumber)
{
    int l = 0, h = numbers.Count - 1, m;
    do
    {
        m = (int)((double)(myNumber - numbers[l]) / (double)(numbers[h] - numbers[l]) * (h - l) + l);
        if (numbers[m] > myNumber) h = m; else l = m;
    }   
    while ((h - l) != 1);
    theAnswer = numbers[l];
}
```

Comment: Welcome and thanks four your help! Please keep in minde to describe your answer and provide some additional information.